# How to sum each row in a named range in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, named-ranges

I'm trying to reverse engineer a budget template so I can modify it. It has sections for different spendatures (Home, Entertainment, Transportation etc). Each section has multiple spendatures (Transportation has Car insurance, gas, parking etc). Each section is a named range, and each spendature is summed to a cell at the right end of the row. However, the template does each row in a section with the same function and I can't figure out how it works.

Here is a picture of it with the function at the top, and the name manager. As I said, the function highlighted is the same exact function in all row totals for 'Daily Living'.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/mbMij.jpg

I have the exact same name groups (name manager and all ranges are identical) and same layout but I can't get that same function produces an error and isn't accepted. The best i've been able to do is put in SUM(Daily) which sums all rows in the section, not each row individually.

Can someone explain this function from the picture `=SUM(Daily[@[January]:[December]])`, particularly the '@' symbol, and how excel knows JAN (in the column header) means January when it isn't in the name manager?

BONUS:
Can someone explain how the section total and overall total functions work as well?
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ydMfz.jpg

Comment: I would suggest you put your 'BONUS' question in a seperate question since it is not related to the topic of your question as said in its title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, lots of things are asked and I hope I'll answer each one. Hope.

First and foremost:  The data layout is a `Table`. A `Table` is different for Excel than the range of cells data appears in of old. It is a formal object in which simple rules are followed and in exchange, Excel, not having to take in all the possible weird things anyone in the world might do in setting things up (I've seen totals cells appear IN data, not below, above, or to the left or right, and in the same range, appear in different rows for different columns. It fit the fellow's scheme, in a feeble-minded way, but what the devil is Excel to make of it when it looks bizarre and confusing to a human? Or ten humans?

In any case, your table is named **Daily**. You can tell it is a table, by the way, due to the way elements of the formula are typed, if for no other reason:  see the square brackets ("[ ]")? Those are almost only ever used in Tables and the odd other place (all of which probably use Table tech to work). Anyhow, when creating the simple `SUM()` formula, when you highlight the whole row, Excel converts the cell addresses you saw as you highlighted to Table references based upon the column Headings:  January through December being the edges of the range you highlight here. So instead of seeing a reference like D20:O20, you get [January:December].

One element left in that formula:  the **@**. Since this is a Table, if you had no way to tell Excel you mean ONLY THIS ROW, it would think you were summing ALL the rows. In Excel, the `@` tells Excel "only this row" and is used not just in Tables and sundry other places, but in a BIG way in using `Spill` formulas. To be explicit, it is telling Excel THIS ROW, so you sum only the Dry Cleaning row, summing up the numbers in all columns between January and December.

In lots of ways, `SUM()` used like here, and `SUBTOTAL()` (used anywhere) are the same, kind of. But `SUBTOTAL()` has a huge difference:  Excel is willing to ignore SUBTOTALs gotten using it when summing a column up. But it won't ignore subtotals created with `SUM()` so if they are in the same column as some raw numbers, you'll get twice the total you should. `SUBTOTAL()` also has a bunch of different things it will return, like an average, that `SUM()` can't by itself.

The person who authored the spreadsheet clearly took a very standard and sensible way of setting up the totaling. He got horizontal totals using `SUM()` so that the vertical totaling he then did would not automatically ignore them and then used `SUBTOTAL()` to make the vertical totaling you see in the Table.

None of these things are in Named Ranges because they are automatically available (so automatic, it's sometimes hard to avoid them...) because the whole thing is a Table. Since it is a Table, you can use column headers as references. Used to be you could do this all the time, but they took it away about 17 years ago, then gave it back in this form... sigh...

Also, sometimes obnoxious is the fact that column headers are automatically text, so they can't be formulas. So dynamic headers are not possible with Tables.

One reason it may not look like a Table is you don't see the obnoxious Filtering icons at the right of each header, usually lying atop part of the header... It is simple to make them go away and the author clearly did so. Lacking those, most would NOT think "Table" for quite a while, but the formation of the formula references is a dead giveaway. Another thing obscuring the fact is most folks are used to having the "green band" appearance with tables (any color, but that paper used to be largely green and I'm 845 years old so...). That too though, can be formatted away when not appropriate, or deemed hateful (Why? Why? It makes screen-wide Tables so-o-o-o-o much more readable!) and in this case, clearly it does not belong. One could use it in each data area, but since they vary in how many rows they each have, that'd be a lot of effort ear in and year out.

So:

1. It's a `Table` and so it has some good things available to you
2. The data is in two sections, the left column with the section and then sub-section (individual rows in your case) headers. Like "Dry Cleaning", and then the "to fill in as it exists over time" section under the January through December headings.
3. Each row is totaled for the year at its right using `SUM()` functions.
4. Each column is totaled for the month (and the year in the rightmost column) using `SUBTOTAL()` functions.
5. The `SUM()` functions work on just one row at a time because they put the `@` before the first item in their range reference ("@January").
6. INDIVIDUAL sections ("INCOME", "HOME", etc.) have totaling for their bits in each month, and for the year, using `SUBTOTAL()` functions because those will be ignored when totaling the overall column. (Contrasting with `SUM()` whose results from each section WOULD be included in the bottom, overall, totals giving results twice the value they should be.)

Very plausibly and usefully laid out with attention to important details. One could argue this kind of thing is better put into a simple table, or even a Table version... a simple Table if you will, and then a pivot table (yes, 845 years old, so cross table, even cross tabs, still sounds normal to me) for presentation. After all, pivot tables, or to be more exact, Power Pivot tables have many advantages (o-o-o-o-o... slicers...) and totaling abilities all their own, and so on and so on, but that's a whole other bit of stuff to learn and this solved someone's needs very nicely.

Not sure what you need to do so I can't offer any help with it. But if you want just to somehow improve on the effort, or to make it yours somehow, you can't really, it's that nicely done. **Unless you go the pivot table route**. So if that's all, save yourself some trouble:  this is very decent and you don't really have improvements to find. If it's just the boss wants something done or else, well, I feel ya, we've all been there.

Comment: Very well written and explained. I think you forgot to explain how the author is able to refer to the columns as 'January' when the cell actually reads JAN?

Also, if you were wondering, the modifications I want to make is to extend it past 1 year (so I need new names for months in 2021+), I want to add a input for my current savings, a section where I can project my investments with interest rates, and other things. You're also correct: I assumed it couldn't be a table because it didn't have the filter buttons on the column headers!

Comment: I've figured it out. In the empty row at the top of each section he's written out the full name of the month as it appears in the formula, but he's made them invisible or hidden.